# Passing arguments after right-clicking the python tkinter button

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have a problem with passing 2 integers after right clicking on the button. Here is my code

```
def r_click(x,y):
    print(x,y)
for x in range(m):
    pole.append([])

    for y in range(n):

        pole[x].append(Button(game_window,width='50',height='40',image=photo,command=lambda x=x, y=y: l_click(x,y)))

        pole[x][y].bind('<Button-3>',lambda x=x, y=y: r_click(x,y))
        pole[x][y].grid(row=x, column=y)
```

Answer (score 0):

All the `bind` event passes an argument to the callback functions by default, so to pass other arguments you have to give one extra parameter at the beginning of the `lambda` function where the first parameter will always receive the default argument whenever the event triggers. in your `bind` function `x` is getting the default argument and `y` is getting what it suppose to. To fix this issue just add another parameter like so.

```py
pole[x][y].bind('<Button-3>', lambda evt, x=x, y=y: r_click(x,y))
```

Hope this helped.